# Text in table to separate rows

Tags: tables, text

I am trying to 'replicate' the style of the following table: [image]

This is what I tried so far:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c c 
}
\toprule
 & OLS-3 & OLS-all & EN & EN & GLM & GLM & NN1 & NN2 & NN5 & NN10 & NN15 \\
 &  &  & FV & TSS & FV & TSS &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 Mean (\%) &  0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Std. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max DD. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max 1M Loss(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Turnover(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 &  & &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \text{Factor timing via the Mean-Variance approach}\\
 Mean (\%) &  0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Std. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max DD. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max 1M Loss(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Turnover(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
\midrule

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:lab}
\end{table}
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image]

This is pretty close to the table I am trying to replicate, except for the text that is separating the two parts of the table. Does anyone know how to centralize the text?

Comment: You shouldn't use `\resizebox` with tables, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Also, as I suppose your real numbers are not all the same, you should load  `siuntx` to align them on the decimal dot. To centre the separating text, use `multicolumn{

Comment: @Bernard what would you replace $\resizebox with? Or should I simply ommit it and not do anything?

Comment: It the table is stoo wide, you can play with the value of `\tabcolsep` and use a smaller font size. The default of `tabcolsep` is 6pt. Reducing it to, say, 4pt saves in your case (12 columns) 144pt (~5cm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```latex
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c c 
            }
            \toprule
            & OLS-3 & OLS-all & EN & EN & GLM & GLM & NN1 & NN2 & NN5 & NN10 & NN15 \\
            &  &  & FV & TSS & FV & TSS &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
            Mean (\%) &  0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Std. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Max DD. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Max 1M Loss(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Turnover(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            &  & &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        & \multicolumn{11}{c}{Factor timing via the Mean-Variance approach}\\
            Mean (\%) &  0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Std. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Max DD. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Max 1M Loss(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            Turnover(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
            \midrule

            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:lab}
\end{table}
```

With the multicolumn the text can be inserted in the center.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `\resizebox` for tables. As a replacement you can use a smaller `\tabcolsep`, a smaller font size and, unless you have special constraints or use marginal notes, you can load `geometry` to have more decent margins.

In the following code, I use the `S` column type, from `siunitx` to ensure numeric values in a column are aligned on the decimal dot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l *{11}{S}}
\toprule
 & {OLS-3} & {OLS-all} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EN} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{GLM} & {NN1} & {NN2} & {NN5} & {NN10} & {NN15} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
 & & & {FV} & {TSS} &{FV} & {TSS} & & & & & \\ \midrule
 Mean (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Std. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max DD. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max 1M Loss(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Turnover(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
\addlinespace[2ex]
 \multicolumn{12}{c}{\bfseries Factor timing via the Mean-Variance approach}\\
 \addlinespace[0.5ex]
 Mean (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Std. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max DD. (\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Max 1M Loss(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
 Turnover(\%) & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
\midrule

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]